# Prevent XXE Attack with JAXB

Tags: java, security, jaxb, ws-security, xxe

Recently, we had a security audit on our code, and one of the problem is that our application is subject to the **Xml eXternal Entity** (XXE) attack.

Basically, the application is a calculator that receives inputs as XML, through a Web-Service.

Here is an example of such an XXE attack on our application:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <foo:calculateStuff>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <xmlInput><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!DOCTYPE currency [  
   <!ENTITY include SYSTEM "file:///d:/" >]>
<calcinput>...</calcinput>
]]></xmlInput>
      </foo:calculateStuff>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

As you can see, we can refer to an entity that points to an external file (`"file:///d:/"`).

Regarding the XML input itself (the `<calcinput>...</calcinput>` part) is unmarshalled with JAXB (v2.1). The web-service part is based on jaxws-rt (2.1).

What do I need to do to secure my web-service?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

**JAXB**

You can prevent the Xml eXternal Entity (XXE) attack by unmarshalling from an `XMLStreamReader` that has the `IS_SUPPORTING_EXTERNAL_ENTITIES` and/or `XMLInputFactory.SUPPORT_DTD` properties set to `false`.

**JAX-WS**

A JAX-WS implementation should take care of this for you. If it doesn't I would recommend opening a bug against the specific implmententation.

---

**EXAMPLE**

***Demo***

```
package xxe;

import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.stream.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);

        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
        xif.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_SUPPORTING_EXTERNAL_ENTITIES, false);
        xif.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.SUPPORT_DTD, false);
        XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(new StreamSource("src/xxe/input.xml"));

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        Customer customer = (Customer) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(customer, System.out);
    }

}
```

***input.xml***

This XML document contains an entity that has been setup to get the listing of files I used to create this example.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE customer
[
<!ENTITY name SYSTEM "/Users/bdoughan/Examples/src/xxe/">
]
>
<customer>
  <name>&name;</name>
</customer>
```

***Customer***

```
package xxe;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Customer {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

***Output - Default Configuration***

By default the entity will be resolved.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<customer>
    <name>Customer.java
Demo.java
input.xml
</name>
</customer>
```

***Output when `XMLInputFactory.IS_SUPPORTING_EXTERNAL_ENTITIES` property is set to `false`***

When this property is set the entity is not resolved.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<customer>
    <name></name>
</customer>
```

***Output when `XMLInputFactory.SUPPORT_DTD` property is set to `false`***

When this property is set an exception is thrown trying to resolve the entity.

```java
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[8,15]
Message: The entity "name" was referenced, but not declared.]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.handleStreamException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:436)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:372)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:342)
    at xxe.Demo.main(Demo.java:18)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[8,15]
Message: The entity "name" was referenced, but not declared.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:598)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.bridge(StAXStreamConnector.java:196)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:370)
    ... 2 more
```

Comment: Thanks for your really detailed answer! I have still a little issue: when I set `xif.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.SUPPORT_DTD, false);
`, I get the following `ParseError`: **The entity "include" was referenced, but not declared**. But if I remove this property (but keep the first one), then the XML is correctly parsed. Any idea?

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan is there a way to enable entities, but limit them to a value say 5 or 10? We receive requests which have "&" in some fields which the user inputs.

Comment: @asgs - You can specify a VM level entity expansion limit.  See:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/03/preventing-entity-expansion-attacks-in.html

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan, is it safe/thread-safe to create one securely configured XMLInputFactory and then create a new XMLStreamReader for each instance document?

Comment: I have a spring MVC webservice in which i have configured marshalling and unmarshalling as above but I am still getting XML external entity injection in a tool Acunetix .Please help !

Comment: @romaintaz You wrote, that you want to secure the web-service. How can you use the `XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();` ? I mean - the parsing is done by the container and what you get is an object...

Comment: [This](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XML_External_Entity_(XXE)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#SAXTransformerFactory) website explains how to block it on several major Java frameworks.

Comment: That works fine, i have tried the way mentioned in https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XML_External_Entity_(XXE)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet but it didn't work.. thanks a lot !

Comment: @bdoughan you are using input.xml as a string but i am using SoapHeader class object like xif.createXMLStreamReader(soapHeader.getSource()), still i am getting same exception in kiwan tool "XML enetity Injection".

Comment: @user1414745  when i convert soapHeader.getSource() into string using TransformerFactory object then its give me error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown configuration property http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD`

Comment: @bdoughan Not sure if you will see this.. but I am using ByteArrayInputStream in unmarshal(). Is it possible to use your suggested answer and use XMLStreamReader? Also, can you elaborate on input.xml file? My question can be found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65295943/prevent-xxe-attack-with-jaxb-xmlstreamreader