# Prevent XXE (External Entity Processing) Attack with JAXB + Spring RESTful Web Services

Tags: spring, web-services, security, jaxb, javax.xml

I know that we can prevent the XXE attack by setting the property `IS_SUPPORTING_EXTERNAL_ENTITIES` in the abstract class `XMLInputFactory` to false in JAXB.

I have also seen this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977299/prevent-xxe-attack-with-jaxb).

My question here is,

How do I create a instance of `XMLInputFactory` and set this `IS_SUPPORTING_EXTERNAL_ENTITIES` property to false when the spring application loads up. And that particular `XMLInputFactory`  instance should only be used for all the JAXB conversion for all the classes that uses `javax.xml.bind.annotation` package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spring uses `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` which is an `AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter` that supports HandlerMethods with the signature -- method argument and return types, defined in `@RequestMapping`.

There are 7 seven `HttpMessageConverters` and one of them is `Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter`

`Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter` is from the spring-web package.

From 3.2.8 version of spring-web onwards Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter sets the processExternalEntities to false which in turn sets the XMLInputFactory property IS_SUPPORTING_EXTERNAL_ENTITIES to false.

Refer : [Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/xml/Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter.html) from Spring

Answer use

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: your page is not opening, this is showing "This page isn’t working".
is It removed ?

Comment: updated the Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter Spring class (hyperlink)