# Prevent XXE attack on jboss 4.2

Tags: java, web-services, jboss, jaxb, xxe

Is it possible to prevent an xxe attack on web service deployed on jboss 4.2 somehow? WS is defined by annotation. I can not find any configuration to disable supporting external entities and dtd.

In this post ([Prevent XXE Attack with JAXB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977299/prevent-xxe-attack-with-jaxb)) is a solution for parsing soap in servlet, but i need something for annotated WS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After long hours of debuging jboss's code I've found a fix for XXE attack on jboss 4.2.2

In DOMUtils.class (located in jbossws-common.jar) I've added extra features on DocumentBuilderFactory instance:

```
factory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities", false);
factory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities", false);
factory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);
```

It solves the problem.

Comment: How did you add these extra features? Was it through some configuration, or you just edited the .class file?

Comment: I found sources of the library, made changes as described above, compiled and replaced just this one class in archive

Comment: i fixed from this source https://github.com/jbossws/jbossws-common/tree/jbossws-common-1.0.4.GA