# Veracode XML External Entity Reference (XXE) unmarshaling org.w3c.dom.Element

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb, xxe

I am getting an XML External Entity Reference (XXE) vulnerability from the code scan audit(Veracode) while unmarshaling an [Element](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html).

```
    public static <T> T unMarshal(org.w3c.dom.Element content, Class<T> clazz) throws JAXBException {
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    return (T) unmarshaller.unmarshal(content, clazz).getValue();
}
```

How can I fix Improper Restriction of XML External Entity Reference ('XXE') in the above code ?

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: How can I fix Improper Restriction of XML External Entity Reference ('XXE') in the above code ?

Comment: I think this one was also posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977299/prevent-xxe-attack-with-jaxb

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent XXE Attack with JAXB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977299/prevent-xxe-attack-with-jaxb)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your example you can try this code:

```
public static <T> T unMarshal(org.w3c.dom.Element content, Class<T> clazz) throws JAXBException, XMLStreamException {
  JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz);
  Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

  XMLInputFactory xmlif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
  xmlif.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_SUPPORTING_EXTERNAL_ENTITIES, false);
  xmlif.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.SUPPORT_DTD, false);
  XMLStreamReader xsr = xmlif.createXMLStreamReader(content);

  return (T) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr, clazz).getValue();
}
```

I think that above solution can resolves an issue related to (CWE 611) XML External Entity Reference