# XMLStreamReader / InputStream xxe vulnerability showing up in Checkmarx report

Tags: java, inputstream, checkmarx, xmlstreamreader, xxe

These lines of code are causing an xxe vulnerability to show up in a Checkmarx report:

```
InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();

XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
XMLStreamReader reader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(is);
```

The issue states that:

"The application sends a request to a remote server, for some resource, using createXMLStreamReader. However, an attacker can control the target of the request, by sending a URL or other data in getInputStream."

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: What is the name of the vulnerability that is found?
Also, can you share the entire code that makes the attack vector as marked by Checkmarx?

Comment: it looks like its causing 2 vulnerabilities, both with the same description I gave, their names are "improper restriction of xxe ref" and another one "SSRF".  They both have destination object of creatXMLStreamReader.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977299/prevent-xxe-attack-with-jaxb looks like it may be answer, still need to verify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found answer that worked for me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977299/prevent-xxe-attack-with-jaxb); add these properties to the XMLInputFactory:

```
XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();

//prevents using external resources when parsing xml
xif.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_SUPPORTING_EXTERNAL_ENTITIES, false);

//prevents using external document type definition when parsing xml
xif.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.SUPPORT_DTD, false);
```