# how to Prevent XML Entity Injection with JAXB

Tags: java, security, jaxb, ws-security, xxe

I refer [Prevent XXE Attack with JAXB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977299/prevent-xxe-attack-with-jaxb/12978808) this link,

but still **kiwan** tool showing me **very heigh VULNERABILITIES** in `xif.createXMLStreamReader(soapHeader.getSource())` line, So please help me if anyone know.

**My code is below like:**

```
SoapHeader soapHeader = ((SoapMessage) message).getSoapHeader();

 XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
 xif.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_SUPPORTING_EXTERNAL_ENTITIES,false);
 xif.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.SUPPORT_DTD, false);

XMLStreamReader soapHeaderXsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(soapHeader.getSource());
unmarshaller.unmarshal(soapHeaderXsr);
```

Thanks.

Comment: You do the right things. I suspect a False Positive from your SAST tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this problem by adding extra XMLInputFactory properties which are :-

> xif.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.SUPPORT_DTD, false);

The safest way to prevent XXE is always to disable DTDs (External Entities) completely.

Set DTD propertie to false for more information refer this [link](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/XML_External_Entity_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html).

now solve my code vulnerabilites

Thank you