# Prevent XXE Attack with JAXB XMLStreamReader

Tags: java, security, jaxb

I am very new to JAXB and in our code audit, there was suggestion on preventing XXE attack with JAXB. I found related answer: [Prevent XXE Attack with JAXB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977299/prevent-xxe-attack-with-jaxb)

My existing code looks like this:

```
if (properties.getProperty(MANIFEST) != null && !properties.getProperty(MANIFEST).isEmpty()) {
                String manifestString =  properties.getProperty(MANIFEST);
                ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(manifestString.getBytes());
                try {
                    this.manifest = (Manifest) getJaxbContext().createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(is);
                }
                catch (JAXBException e) {
                    LOG.warn("There was an error trying to convert xml String to Manifest - {}", e.getMessage(), e);
                }
                
            }
```

Based on the answer, instead of using `ByteArrayInputStream`, I am supposed to use `XMLStreamReader` with some properties `false`.

In suggested answer, it says:

`XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(new StreamSource("src/xxe/input.xml"));`

I don't understand what 'src/xxe/input.xml' is and what it needs to be for my solution. Can anyone please explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `src/xxe/input.xml` from the answer in the other question is that question's source location for the XML being processed - namely a filename, accessed as a URL resource.

In your case, your XML is provided in `String manifestString` - therefore your `StreamSource` needs to be given this string as its source, not a file location.

This can be done using a `StringReader`:

```java
import java.io.StringReader

...

StringReader manifestReader = new StringReader(manifestString); 
XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(new StreamSource(manifestReader));
```

I split the code into 2 lines to make it clearer - but you can collapse them back to one line if you prefer:

```java
XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(
        new StreamSource(new StringReader(manifestString)));
```

The above code assumes you have already created your context and the `xif` input factory:

```java
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Manifest.class);
XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
xif.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_SUPPORTING_EXTERNAL_ENTITIES, false);
xif.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.SUPPORT_DTD, false);
```

Then you can unmarshal in the usual way:

```java
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
Manifest manifest = (Manifest) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr);
```